# Explicit general formula for $n!$ permutation matrices for column vector $ \pi = (1 \cdots n)^{T} $

Tags: matrices, symmetric-groups

I am looking for an explicit general formula of $ n!$ permutation matrices for the initial column vector $\pi = \begin{pmatrix} 1,  2  \cdots \ n \end{pmatrix}^{T}$.

The first permutation vector is $\pi^{I} = \pi$ and the first permutation matrix is the identity matrix:

$
\pi^{I}= P^{I}_{\pi} \pi
$

$
P^{I}_{\pi} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$

The second permutation vector is $\pi^{II} = \begin{pmatrix} 2,  1 \ \cdots \ n \end{pmatrix}^{T}$ and the corresponding permutation matrix is $P^{II}_{\pi}$ as follows:

$
\pi^{II}= P^{II}_{\pi} \pi
$

$
P^{II}_{\pi} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$

I would like to get the expression of the $K^{th}$ permutation matrix $P^{K}_{\pi}$ for the $K^{th}$ permutation, $1 \leq K \leq n!$

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is a 'matrix for a vector'?

Comment: I edited the question to explain better

Comment: How do you define the $K^{th}$ permutation? There are different ways to generate them.

Comment: @Damien I would say there are different ways to "list" or "order" them, since "generate" already means something else in the context of group theory.

Comment: I don't know how to define $K^{th}$ permutation,  how can I make it?

Comment: @runway44 Effectively. I am biased by my coding activity. "How to write a code to generate them?"

Comment: I am looking for an analytical expression of $P^{K}_{\pi}$ not for numerical one

Comment: I don't think there's a meaningful way to enumerate every single permutation

Answer (score 0):

Permutations can be represented by the corresponding permutations of the columns of the identity matrix. i.e. $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&1&0\end{bmatrix}$$ represents the permutation $(1,3,2)$, since we swapped columns one and two, then we get the permutation that maps $2\mapsto 3$ and $3\mapsto 2$.

Comment: I am looking  for a general formula of $P^{K}_{\pi}$